# Convert vcf to hap file, collapse genotypes

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I use photos to ask a question.

- I have a [vcf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkkaQ.png).
- And a [R-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w52x5.png).
- This is what my output looks like: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycsfk.png)

I want my output file only have number/line/sample.

How can I remove newdata...C...and ""

Any suggestions?

**Note:** I am the first time to ask a question in here. I am try to follow the rules.
I am still studying.

Comment: please read the answers provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
library(data.table)

# example vcf
hap <- fread('
##fileformat=VCFv4.0
##fileDate=20090805
##source=myImputationProgramV3.1
##reference=1000GenomesPilot-NCBI36
##phasing=partial
##INFO=<ID=NS,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Number of Samples With Data">
##INFO=<ID=AN,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Total number of alleles in called genotypes">
##FILTER=<ID=q10,Description="Quality below 10">
##FILTER=<ID=s50,Description="Less than 50% of samples have data">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001 NA00002 NA00003
19  111 .   A   C   9.6 .   .   GT  0|0 0|0 0|1
19  112 .   A   G   10  .   .   GT  0|0 1|0 1|1
19  112 .   A   G   4   .   .   GT  1|0 1|0 1|1
')

data.table(gsub("|", "", do.call(paste0, hap[, -c(1:9)]), fixed = TRUE))
#        V1
# 1: 000001
# 2: 001011
# 3: 101011
```